# Apache camel app behaves differently in Tomcat when deployed with Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat, apache-camel

I do not understand the situation: whe I use Maven to deploy Apache camel routes to the Tomcat I do not see any routes with JMX. But if I package war with Maven and deploy it manually (copy *.war to webapps directory) - everything works fine.

What could cause such a behavior!?

Comment: How do you do the deployment? Maven Plugin? Via command line or from within IDE ?

Comment: I am using tomcat7-maven-plugin and Tomcat 8 instance.

Comment: Do you get any errors message etc. during deployment in Tomcat.